# AS3 Associating Loader Content to Other Frame

Tags: loader, swfloader

Helo,
I've problem to remote my SWF outside its loaded frame in the same timeline. I would like to use all function inside the Loader associated in other frame.Shortly, it seems like to make variable reffering the **contentLoaderInfo** to bring to other frame. How it done?

Please help